# XSLT - Convert URI backslashes to forward slash

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, dita

We are converting legacy HTML files to DITA. I would like to convert windows paths with backslashes in the href attribute

```
<a href="c:\developer\file.html">
```

to forward slashes

```
<xref href="c:/developer/file.dita">
```

I have attempted to use both replace and translate (XSLT is v2) with no success. I have also tried the string.replace method on http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx with the same result.

Comment: What did your calls to `translate` look like? This should do the job but you may have to consider some escaping.

Comment: I've tried a billion different ways. Here are two that were unsuccessful:  select="translate('\', node(), '/')" and "translate(., '\', '/') What compounds the problem is we are using a canned XSL from the DITA-OT called h2d.xsl. It's hard to understand where it's writing the original links.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have attempted to use both replace and translate (XSLT is v2) with
>   no success.

```
translate(@href, '\', '/')
```

should work just fine. Or, if you prefer to do it all in one, try:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xref href="{replace(replace(@href, '\\', '/'), '.html', '.dita') }">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xref>
</xsl:template>
```